# Ajax request to get data in Raphael js

Tags: ajax, raphael

I want to send a ajax request to load some data (json) on mouseover event of my circle and display the costume data in a pup up window over my circle.
any idea how to handle this?

```
r.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
    fill: "CadetBlue",
    stroke: "black"
}).mouseover(function (e) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
});
```

Comment: I know how to send request in extjs or jquery but in raphael im not sure that was as simple, i dont know how to specify the method and url and the parameters which i want to send to server and get related data. i think i should write a pure javascript code for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an ajax query like this :

```
r.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
    fill: "CadetBlue",
    stroke: "black"
}).mouseover(function (e) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

                // do stuff, for example show a popup

            } else {

                // fail

            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
});
```

Comment: I try yours but httpRequest.readyState and httpRequest.status are always 0 and request failed! why?

Comment: 0 means unitialized. Did you pass a valid URL and call send() ? If the server answers, your onreadystatechange will be called more than once with the different status.

Comment: i called it locally, i create a simple json text file beside my js file: httpRequest.open('GET', 'data.txt'); is it wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work with local files (this is a HTTP request). Open you file using http:// (this means you need a local http server to develop).